# How can I do color output for cucumber tests in jenkins console output?

Tags: jenkins, cucumber, jenkins-pipeline

I use Jenkins pipeline for run cucumber tests. When I run cucumber test in bash console I see colorful output. But in Jenkins console output only single color text.
I run cucumber test from bash script file and I have tried add to this file:

```
CUCUMBER_COLORS='passed=green,bold:passed_param=green,skipped=cyan,bold:skipped_param=cyan,failed=red,bold:failed_paramm=red,pedning=yellow'
export CUCUMBER_COLORS
```

like in this article https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Console-Colours
but it's not help.

Answer (score 0):

Please install the ANSIColor plugin  from https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/AnsiColor+Plugin
Then you will get color output.

Comment: I have installed it, but it's not help. Output still single color.

Comment: have you added it to your job/build configuration?

Comment: Yes, of course. I heve added config `ansiColor('xterm')` to my build config. I have two build, it's rspec and cucumber. For rspec this plugin work good, but for cucumber only one type of error colored.

Comment: for cucumber, the monochrome option should be set as false to get colored output. please try it

Comment: Sorry, but where I can set this option?

Comment: that is jvm version, for ruby version, the option is color or no-color. by default is enabled. you can set by command line like cucumber --color

Comment: It's not help :(

Comment: Team,
I am running the Protractor Cucumber framework in Jenkins Headless mode.

The Feature, Scenario, Step names are not printing in the Jenkins console. How can we enable it?

Answer (score 0):

If you still have this problem probably this can help.
Put option --color in the cucumber command

```
Like this
```

> cucumber -p you_custom_profile --format json --color

This works for me.
Also do not forget install ANSIColor plugin as well